Incorrect timezone with casting datetime string (earlier than 1948 year) to timestamptz or timetz
Linux or Windows, it's no matter.
PostgreSQL version from 14 to 15.3 at least.
set time zone 'Antarctica/Syowa';

select '1947-01-01 08:00:00'::timestamptz,
       '1948-01-01 08:00:00'::timestamptz,
       '1947-01-01 08:00:00'::timestamptz at time zone 'ETC/UTC';

Result:

So, it's just wrong time zone because right is +3 offset from UTC.
And it's moreover.
Some timezones show incorrect result with different top right years:
Asia/Aqtau - earlier 1931 year
Indian/Comoro - earlier 1943 year
and so on...
What is going on with timezones?

Why do you think it's wrong? What source did you use for "the truth" about the time zones?

@Frank Heikens
SELECT     name,     abbrev,     utc_offset,     is_dst FROM pg_timezone_names;

How does that relate to a date in 1947?

I want that all timezones with all dates will be equal to the list above. I don't care about what timezones or rules were before 1947 year for example.

But time zones do vary over time - any model which insists on a single UTC offset forever is just going to be inaccurate. What's the benefit of that inaccuracy to you?

@Jon Skeet Ok. Maybe I got carried away. It's the just small use case with timetz that need to be extracted from some timestamptz. I stored a default row with value 1700-01-02 08:00:00+[some timezone] as the work day start time. But a table schema was changed and now this field need to be converted into timetz field with +00 timezone (don't ask why, please). But it's failed due to the timezone rules and migration script is need to be fixed.


So, it's just wrong time zone because right is +3 offset from UTC.

No, that's not the case - at least, not according to the IANA time zone database which I suspect is what Postgres is using.
I personally use my own Noda Time tzvalidate page to check these things, but that's based on the data which you can see in GitHub in Paul Eggert's repo - or download from IANA, but it's simpler to browse on GitHub.
You can see there in the backward file that Antarctica/Syowa is a link to Asia/Riyadh, and in the asia file we can see the following rules:
# Zone  NAME        STDOFF  RULES   FORMAT [UNTIL]
Zone    Asia/Riyadh 3:06:52 -       LMT    1947 Mar 14
                    3:00    -       %z

So basically Postgres is doing exactly what I'd expect, for that data source.
